# Lottery program numbers generator

Tags: java

I am making a lottery simulation for my class project and I can not get it to not repeat the same numbers. All else is working fine, but I've tried several ways of getting it to not repeat numbers that have already been drawn but I just cant get it working. I'm fairly new at this.

```
class Lotto
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        System.out.print("Hvor mange rekker vil du spille?: ");
        Scanner lesInn= new Scanner(System.in);// Gir brukeren mulighet til å taste inn antall rekker de vil spille. (How many tickets)  
        int nummer = lesInn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Lotto tallene er: ");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0; i<nummer; i++)
        {
            int[] lottoNummer = trekk();
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[1] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[2] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[3] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[4] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[5] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[6] + " " );
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[7] + " " );
            System.out.print("Tilleggstall:(" + lottoNummer[7] + ")");
            System.out.println();
        }//for
    }//main

    public static int[] trekk()
    {
        int[] lottoNummer = new int[8];
        {
            lottoNummer[1] = (int) ((34 * Math.random()) + 1);
            lottoNummer[2] = (int) ((34 * Math.random()) + 1);
            lottoNummer[3] = (int) ((34 * Math.random()) + 1);
            lottoNummer[4] = (int) ((34 * Math.random()) + 1);
            lottoNummer[5] = (int) ((34 * Math.random()) + 1);
            lottoNummer[6] = (int) ((34 * Math.random()) + 1);
            lottoNummer[7] = (int) ((34 * Math.random()) + 1);
        }
        bubbleSort(lottoNummer);
        return lottoNummer;
    }//trekk

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] x)
    {
        int k, y, i;
        for( y = 1; y <= x.length -1; y++)
        for( i= 0 ; i <= x.length -2; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] > x [i+1])
            {
                k = x[i];
                x[i]= x[i+1];
                x[i+1] = k;
            }// if
        }//for
    }//bubbleSort
}//class
```

Comment: If you have already selected a number, reject it and try again.,

Comment: You want to reject duplicate numbers in `trekk` right? if thats so then after the first random you will have to check the previous drawn numbers and redraw ( call random again ) so you will skip the duplications. To achieve that you either store the drawn numbers somewhere or evaluate the array which you store the numbers for return.

Comment: Generate all numbers in an ArrayList, call Collections.shuffle, and use the first n numbers from the list.

Comment: "You want to reject duplicate numbers in trekk right?"
Yes, but I am unsure on what that code would look like, or where it would fit in. As I said I am fairly new at this, only been coding for a few weeks. This is only the start of the program and I need a lot more but I need to get past this place first. If anyone would like to edit the code or give me an example of how it would look and where it would go I would be most grateful, I've been at it for 4 hours now and nothing I do seem to work, and I know it's probably just a small thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use the Stream API in that case. So as i think it should be so:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hvor mange rekker vil du spille?: ");
        Scanner lesInn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nummer = lesInn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Lotto tallene er: ");
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < nummer; i++) {
            int[] lottoNummer = trekk();
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[1] + " ");
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[2] + " ");
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[3] + " ");
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[4] + " ");
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[5] + " ");
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[6] + " ");
            System.out.print(lottoNummer[7] + " ");
            System.out.print("Tilleggstall:(" + lottoNummer[7] + ")");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[] trekk() {
        return new Random().ints(1, 35).distinct().limit(8).sorted().toArray();
    }
```

Creating a random stream of integers where the first digit is for min value, the last one for max value. Distinct is for making only unique numbers, Limit is for limiting size of an array and Sorted is obviously for sorting. And then mapping it to an array and returning.

Actually, I would like to refactor a little bit your code if you don't mind, this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hvor mange rekker vil du spille?: ");
        Scanner lesInn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nummer = lesInn.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Lotto tallene er: ");
        System.out.println();

        for (int i = 0; i < nummer; i++) {
            int[] lottoNummer = trekk();
            for (int num : lottoNummer) {
                System.out.print(num + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("Tilleggstall:(" + lottoNummer[lottoNummer.length - 1] + ")");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static int[] trekk() {
        return new Random().ints(1, 35).distinct().limit(8).sorted().toArray();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Ive tried to use this but I can't get it to work. Where does it go, do I replace anything? Do I need to remove what I've got? Sorry but I really need hand holding here :-(

Comment: Yes, you should replace your method called trekk() with it.

Comment: Am I right, array lottoNummer has 8 elements and you need different unique numbers from 1 to 34?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I will try to replace the method. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: Hope it'll work. If it is, please don't forget to accept my answer.

Comment: I am sorry , but I just can't get it to work. Could you copy my code, edit it and try to run it the way you think it should be and see if it runs, if it does copy your edited version back ? Sorry, I know I am asking a lot, but I just can't seem to get this done and I've been at this for so many hours now. Really appreciate all the help.

Comment: Done. I repair Stream a little.

Comment: Wow, thank you issverg! This was a much better solution that what I had done. Thank you so much for bothering to help me with this and taking the time to do it so well. Much appreciated. I have accepted your fantastic answer! Have a great day!

Comment: With pleasure! Have a nice weekend!